# Store random line values in data structure

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a program which creates 9 biomorphs which are evolved somehow from a middle biomorph. Currently, I have 9 showing although these are completely random. What is the best way to store the values of the initial biomorph to be used in the other 8?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BiomorphObject extends JPanel {

Graphics2D g2d;
Dimension size = getSize();
int w = size.width;
int h = size.height;
Random ran = new Random();
int x1;
int x2;
int y1;
int y2;

public BiomorphObject(Graphics g){

    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100)) % w + 120;
    int y = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100)) % h;
    int xMirror = x - 120;
    g2d.drawLine(120, 85, x, y);
    g2d.drawLine(120, 85, 120 - xMirror, y);

    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
    x2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(50)) % w + 120;
    y2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(50)) % h;

    paintBiomorph(g);
}

public void paintBiomorph(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        int xMirror1 = x1 - 120;
        int xMirror2 = x2 - 120;
        g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        g2d.drawLine(120 - xMirror1, y1, 120 - xMirror2, y2);
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
        x2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100)) % w + 120;
        y2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100)) % h;
    }
}
```

}

This is a screenshot of the current GUI I have:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/I6qweT7.png]

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the Random() method in a painting method. You can't control when Swing will repaint a component and you don't want the painting to randomly change.

Instead you need to create properties in your class that the painting method can use to do the custom painting. So you should create a `Biomorph` object. This object will contain the information necessary to paint a single `Biomorph`. It should even contain a method to paint itself. Lets call this method paintBiomorph(Graphics).

When you create the Biomorph object you might have an empty constructor which creates a random Biomorph, then you might have a constructor that takes a Biomporh object as a parameter so you can create "child" Biomorphs based on a "parent" Biomorph.

Then you can create an `ArrayList` hold multiple `Biomorh` objects. Then in the `paintComponent()` method you iterate through the ArrayList and simply invoke the paintBoimorph(GRaphics) method on each `Biomorph` object.

The Random() method would only be used when you initially create a Biomorph object. After than all the data need to repaint the Biomorph must be part of the object itself.

Edit:

The Biomorph class might look something like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Biomorph extends JPanel
{
    List<Shape> lines = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    //Graphics2D g2d;
    //Dimension size = getSize();
    //int w = size.width;
    //int h = size.height;
    //Random ran = new Random();
    //int x1;
    //int x2;
    //int y1;
    //int y2;

    public Biomorph()
    {

        //g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        //g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        Random ran = new Random();
        int x = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100)) + 120;
        int y = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100));
        int xMirror = x - 120;
//        g2d.drawLine(120, 85, x, y);
//        g2d.drawLine(120, 85, 120 - xMirror, y);
        lines.add( new Line2D.Double(120, 85, x, y);
        lines.add( new Line2D.Double(120, 85, -x, y);

        int x1 = x;
        int y1 = y;
        int x2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(50)) + 120;
        int y2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(50));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            int xMirror1 = x1 - 120;
            int xMirror2 = x2 - 120;
            //g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            //g2d.drawLine(120 - xMirror1, y1, 120 - xMirror2, y2);
            lines.add( new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            lines.add( new Line2D.Double(-x1, y1, -x2, y2);

            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
            x2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100)) + 120;
            y2 = Math.abs(ran.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor( getForeground() );

        for (Shape line: lines)
        {
            g2d.fill( line );
            //g2d.draw( line );
        }

        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have separated the constructor and the paint method, and attempted to call the paint in the constructor. However, when I try to call the biomorph object in the GUI, it says that I need a matching parameter to implement Graphics 2D, BUT I do not want to call this there, and the GUI doesn't seem to run. I have made the changes above for you to look at.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is you need to store the lines that make up the Biomorph so the lines can be painted. I made a quick attempt to modify your class using this approach. Then somehow you need to relate the child Biomorph's to the parent Biomorph. I don't know how you do this. Maybe you just use the same x/y value? If so, then you need to change the constructor to pass in the starting x/y value for each Biomorph.